# lsp-jedi debugging

Tags: lsp-mode, jedi

I've encountered issues with `lsp-jedi` apparently sending a bad message to `jedi-language-server` which causes an `Invalid Params` error in Pythons `pygls`.

Having sought assistance from the author(s) of `jedi-language-server`[1] who suggested it might be an error in `lsp-jedi`[2]  who suggested it was an error in the former I asked the authors of `pygls`[3] who suggested its a poorly formed command.

I'm stumped as to how to go about finding the call being made from Emacs though and would be grateful of advice.

I load `lsp-jedi` with...

```lisp
(use-package lsp-jedi
  :ensure t
  :config
  (with-eval-after-load "lsp-mode"
    (add-to-list 'lsp-disabled-clients 'pyls)
    (add-to-list 'lsp-enabled-clients 'jedi)))
```

But none of the commands defined in [`lsp-jedi`](https://github.com/fredcamps/lsp-jedi/blob/master/lsp-jedi.el) are then available such as `lsp-jedi-debug` and so adding `(setq lsp-jedi-debug t)` to the above `:config` didn't help.

I tried starting `emacs --debug` or `emacs --debug-init` and then opening a `.py` file but nothing pertaining to `lsp-mode` was shown in the `*Backtrace*` buffer.

Setting `toggle-debug-on-error t` didn't help since the error occurs external to Emacs after `lsp-jedi` has sent its commands to `jedi-language-server`.

The error that occurs is...

```lisp
Server jedi:12920/starting exited with status exit(check corresponding stderr buffer for details). Do you want to restart it? (y or n)
```

...and it never starts. In `*jedi::stderr*` the following error is shown...

```python
Process jedi stderr finished
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygls/protocol.py", line 152, in deserialize_message
    deserialize_params(data, get_params_type)
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygls/protocol.py", line 138, in deserialize_params
    data['params'] = params_type(**params)
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 406, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for InitializeParams
processId
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/bin/jedi-language-server", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jedi_language_server/cli.py", line 125, in cli
    SERVER.start_io()
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygls/server.py", line 204, in start_io
    self.loop.run_until_complete(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygls/server.py", line 75, in aio_readline
    proxy(b''.join(message))
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygls/protocol.py", line 456, in data_received
    json.loads(body.decode(self.CHARSET),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 359, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygls/protocol.py", line 154, in deserialize_message
    raise JsonRpcInvalidParams()
pygls.exceptions.JsonRpcInvalidParams: Invalid Params
```

`*lsp-log*` shows

```
Command "jedi-language-server" is present on the path.
Command "pyls" is not present on the path.
Command "pylsp" is not present on the path.
Command "jedi-language-server" is present on the path.
Command "pyls" is not present on the path.
Command "pylsp" is not present on the path.
Found the following clients for /home/neil/work/python/tcx2gpx/setup.py: (server-id jedi, priority -1)
The following clients were selected based on priority: (server-id jedi, priority -1)
```

The most frustrating thing is I use the same configuration home and work servers but this only occurs on my home server.

Any pointers on how to find out what `lsp-jedi` is requesting so I can investigate, as per the authors of `pygls` suggestion[3], whether its a malformed request or something on the server side would be very much appreciated.

1. [Language servers exits · Issue #208 · pappasam/jedi-language-server](https://github.com/pappasam/jedi-language-server/issues/208)
2. [Starting jedi-language-server fails... · Issue #20 · fredcamps/lsp-jedi](https://github.com/fredcamps/lsp-jedi/issues/20)
3. [pydantic throws ValidationError · Issue #243 · openlawlibrary/pygls](https://github.com/openlawlibrary/pygls/issues/243)

Comment: Did you noticed on this page https://github.com/fredcamps/lsp-jedi the special configuration to work with virtual environments? is this enabled?

Comment: The module ```pylsp``` https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-pylsp/- shows already ```jedi``` module is enabled, and some other items related to working in virtual environments could be also enabled (currently disabled).

Comment: @Ian yes I'd seen those and had originally been using `jedi-language-server` _after_ having activated venv under Emacs, but was advised that it should be system wide. I was keen to get `jedi-language-server` working rather than `lsp-pylsp` relying on `jedi` as it seemed a neater/cleaner solution, plus I read [here](https://www.mattduck.com/lsp-python-getting-started.html) about a Jedi version issue. Maybe I should revisit `pyls`, thanks for the pointers.